# Format Altair choropleth map legend scale and tooltip

Tags: tooltip, legend, altair, choropleth

I am trying to make the tool tip 'Percentage' be an actual percent and not a decimal. Even when I include `alt.Tooltip('Percentage:Q',format='.2%')`, it doesn't seem to work.

Also, I am trying to make the legend scale from 0-100% instead of 40-70%.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'states')
variable_list = ['Percentage', 'State Name', 'state_id']

alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape().encode(
color=alt.Color('Percentage:Q', title='Positive NFB', legend=alt.Legend(format=".0%"), scale=alt.Scale(scheme='yellowgreen')),
tooltip=['State Name:N', 'Percentage:Q', alt.Tooltip('Percentage:Q',format='.2%')]).properties(title="Percentage of People in Households with Positive NFB"
).transform_lookup(
lookup='id',
from_=alt.LookupData(states_positive_NFB, 'state_id', variable_list)
).properties(
width=500,
height=300
).project(
type='albersUsa'
)
```

Current map:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

- To change the domain of the color scale, you can pass the `domain` argument to `alt.Scale()`: e.g.

  ```python
  alt.Scale(scheme='yellowgreen', domain=[0, 1])
  ```
- To make the tooltip format appear, you can remove the duplicated tooltip encoding, as the first one appears to be taking precedence. That is, rather than

  ```python
  tooltip=['State Name:N', 'Percentage:Q', alt.Tooltip('Percentage:Q',format='.2%')]
  ```

  you should use

  ```python
  tooltip=['State Name:N', alt.Tooltip('Percentage:Q', format='.2%')]
  ```

Comment: Is it possible to add the percentages directly on to the individual states? Or is the tool tip the only option?

Comment: @MorganMcCue You can use `mark_text()` with longitude and latitude similar to this example https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/airports_count.html